# Speaker Recognition API Identification Profile - Create Enrollment: How to record audio in the specified format from web page?

Tags: javascript, azure, wav, azure-cognitive-services, recorder.js

The audio file format must meet the following requirements.

- Container      WAV
- Encoding       PCM
- Rate           16K
- Sample Format  16 bit
- Channels       Mono.

How to achieve this from web page? Can't find any resources:(

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg (See the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation), or the man page with `man ffmpeg`)

This command will change any audio or video to

- PCM 16bit (`-acodec pcm_s16le`)
- 16K (`-ar 16000`)
- Mono (`-ac 1`)

`ffmpeg -i input.any -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 16000 output.wav`

For web, there are multiple options here are 2

1. github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC
2. https://github.com/rposbo/speaker-recognition-api/blob/master/recorder.js

Comment: how can i do this from web page?

Comment: This seems to work https://github.com/rposbo/speaker-recognition-api/blob/master/recorder.js